# C++ create structure to refactor resource allocation code in multiple files

Tags: c++, class, unit-testing, refactoring, odbc

I am writing unit tests against an ODBC driver on MAC. Hence, every time I am trying to build a test, I need to declare the following variables to allocate resources.

```
    SQLRETURN rc;
    SQLHENV h_env;
    SQLHDBC h_conn;
    SQLHSTMT h_stmt;
    char full_dsn[500];
```

I am thinking to put them in a structure, or class so that every time I need the above, I just call to initialize it. But I do not know how to specifically do it code-wise, and what would be the smartest elegant method.

Besides, at the end of the fucntions, I need to call a few free function to clean up. How could I wrap those in an function that's accessible by all files under this project?

EDIT:
We have decided to use **struct**. So we will have:

```
struct ODBCRes {
        SQLRETURN rc;
        SQLHENV h_env;
        SQLHDBC h_conn;
        SQLHSTMT h_stmt;
        char full_dsn[500];

        functions (){...}

        ~destructorFns() {
            ...
        }
    };
```

I am not sure how I should structure this so that the project code be elegant. 
I want to put this struct code into a separate file, and then call this struct in other unit tests files. But I am not sure how I should deal with the .hh files and .cc files.
If I just put the struct code in a .cc file, and include that in unit_test_a.cc, then I think that's copying the entire code still... But how do I do it with .hh file and how do I arrange the file structures please? Would I need `typedef` here?

Could someone help with example code please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to put those variables in a class, and inherit all test functions from that class. Something like that:

```
class TestBase {
 public: 
  TestBase() = default;
  ~TestBase() { /* put free functions to cleanup here */ }
 protected:
  SQLRETURN rc;
  SQLHENV h_env;
  SQLHDBC h_conn;
  SQLHSTMT h_stmt;
  char full_dsn[500];
};

class UnitTest : public TestBase {
 public:
  void TestSomething() { /*variables are accessible here */ }
};
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. We decided to use struct instead. Could you please provide some examples on how I should structure the files please? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, the only difference between struct and class in C++ is that struct members are by default public, while class members are by default private, otherwise it is the same thing. So you can just change the class to struct in example provided. (As a side note - as I don't see big difference between struct or class, I do not understand the logic behind your decision - why struct instead of class :) )?